# Activiti + Spring MVC integration OR Vaadin

Tags: spring-mvc, vaadin, activiti, business-process-management

New in BPM world and trying to understand the opensource tools for web project.    Following are my doubts:

- If I dont want to use Activiti gui screens, is it possible to start a project with Spring MVC and use the rest component of Activiti to serve my purpose completely? No good example found exploiting this feature in web.

Is Vaadin build over activiti Or just gui components like bootstrap?

- Can I develop an entire web app using Vaadin?

Comment: Yes, Vaadin van be used to create a full web application. I personally like to use Spring boot to make it even more versatile. No idea about Activiti

Answer (score 2):

You can build your own UI on top of the Activiti java/REST API's. Many people do this. There is nothing special here (hence why you won't find specialized Actviti REST + UI docs), as it's a REST API that you call like many others.

It's worth to note that the next version of Activiti (v6) will move from Vaadin to AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Activiti Community version is built on Vaadin.
And Yes, you can create your own custom UI by using activiti's Rest APIs to make query on your running activiti process engine.

Answer (score 0):

BP3 produces an Angular framework that handles all the Activiti REST communication. Check it out here: http://www.bp-3.com/brazosopen/